# how to say something cannot be that way

Tags: relative-clauses, subjunctives, complements, infinitive-phrases

This text was written by [coffee1054](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13752) in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/please-show-me-my-mistakes):

> You might feel that it is impossible **for** resistance **be** strictly equal to
>   zero: maybe it leads to some contradiction with Ohm's law.

In the sentence above, it feels as though some word is missing, or that maybe "for" is the wrong word there. How can the sentence be changed?

Comment: You might feel that it is impossible for resistance **to** be strictly equal to zero: maybe it leads to some contradiction with Ohm's law.

Comment: How exactly do you want to change the sentence? What meaning do you think it should convey? Also, please source your quotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence would be grammatically better if it were

> "... that it is impossible for resistance *to* be strictly zero."

The usage "for-xxx-be" can be grammatically correct in other scenarios, such as

> "It is mandatory that all references *for resistance be* in terms of ohm only."

However, in the scenario you mention, a `*to*` is necessary.